# wget 403 forbidden error

Tags: curl, wget

I am trying to download the source code for this site:
http://www.autotrader.ca/cars/bmw/3%20series/qc/montr%C3%A9al/?kwd=335I&prx=100&prv=Quebec&loc=Montreal%2c+QC&trans=Automatic&body=Sedan&sts=New-Used&yRng=2013%2c2014&hprc=True&wcp=True&inMarket=advancedSearch

I tried both wget and curl, but i keep getting 403 forbidden error
Is there any way to go around this error?

Comment: Please note that stackoverflow is about issues aroound code development. Could you be more specific as to why this is related to code? Also, maybe the special characters are improperly wrote on your command line?

Comment: Im trying to create a webcrawler to search autotrader to find a car, and i need to get the html source code, and this is the simplest method i came across

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website needs `Accept-Language` header, it's used to return different content based on the language used, you'll also need to change the user-agent :

```
curl -s -L -c 'cookies.txt' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=1.0' \
     -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36' \
     'http://www.autotrader.ca/cars/bmw/3%20series/qc/montr%c3%a9al/?kwd=335I&prx=100&prv=Quebec&loc=Montreal%2c+QC&trans=Automatic&body=Sedan&sts=New-Used&yRng=2013%2c2014&hprc=True&wcp=True&inMarket=advancedSearch'
```